# how to remove negetive value in nested list

Tags: python, list

I'm new to Python programming and I've written the following code:

```py
y = [[-1, -2, 4, -3, 5], [2, 1, -6], [-7, -8, 0], [-5, 0, -1]]
for row in y:
    for col in row:
        if col < 0:
            row.remove(col)
print(y)
```

I want to remove elements with **negative** values from the nested list. However, when two negative values are adjacent, the code doesn't remove the second value. What modifications can I make to ensure the removal of all negative values?

Comment: Don't change the length of a list while iterating over it...

Comment: `[[j for j in i if j>=0] for i in y]`?

Comment: Good question for first time of programming. Go ahead with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may never remove items form a list while iterating it, you'd keep the ones you need, the positive ones

```
y = [[col for col in row if col>=0] for row in y]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
[[item for item in arr if item >= 0] for arr in y]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use filter and lambda function:

```py
    y = [[-1, -2, 4, -3, 5], [2, 1, -6], [-7, -8, 0], [-5, 0, -1]]

    y = [list(filter(lambda col: col >= 0, row)) for row in y]

    print(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of [`map`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-map-function/) and list comprehensions.

Here's an example:

```
y = [[-1, -2, 4, -3, 5], [2, 1, -6], [-7, -8, 0], [-5, 0, -1]]
y = list(map(lambda row: [col for col in row if col >= 0], y))
print(y)
```

Output:

```
[[4, 5], [2, 1], [0], [0]]
```